# SQL Server calculation or metric using aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, rowcount

I have a problem in SQL Server that I have no clue how to fix. From the below query and output I need to generate the following metric: ATP (available to promise) on the size level as a percentage i.e:

1. there are 3 sizes, 2 have qtys - 1 does not. If there is any qty then I want to return the value '1' if not '0' (the CASE statement)
2. that leaves 2 with a value of '1' and 1 with '0' (2/3) or 66% 'Full Size ATP'

How can I generate that calculation with the query below? I tried `COUNT` on the `CASE` statement with no luck.

Appreciate the help.

Query:

```
    SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
       M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       DATEPART(mm,AVAIL_DATE) AS 'MONTH',
      CASE 
            WHEN A.AVAIL_QTY IS NULL 
            THEN '0'
            ELSE A.AVAIL_QTY
       END AS 'AVAIL_QTY', 
      COUNT(AVAIL_QTY) AS 'COUNT_ATP_QTY',
      COUNT(AVAIL_QTY)/COUNT(*) AS 'ATP %'
FROM   VW_MM_SALES_GRID M LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A 
    ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
    AND A.SIZE_LITERAL = M.SIZE_LITERAL
    AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')
    AND A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

WHERE  M.MATERIAL = 'AA2721' AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY A.MATERIAL, 
         M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
         AVAIL_DATE, 
         A.AVAIL_QTY,
         A.STOCK_CATEGORY

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Results:

```
MATERIAL           SIZE_LITERAL MONTH       AVAIL_QTY                               COUNT_ATP_QTY ATP %
------------------ ------------ ----------- --------------------------------------- ------------- -----------
NULL               S            NULL        0                                       0             0
AA2721             L            8           45                                      1             1
AA2721             M            8           51                                      1             1
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3 row(s) affected)


-----------
3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - you need to get one row per material in the results because you are calculating the aggregate (ATP), and NULL does not get counted so you don't need to use the CASE, you can just count the non-NULLs and divide by the total count.

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(A.AVAIL_QTY, 0)) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS [Full Size ATP]
FROM VW_MM_SALES_GRID M LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A 
    ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
    AND A.SIZE_LITERAL = M.SIZE_LITERAL
    AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')
    AND A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90
WHERE  M.MATERIAL = 'AA2721' AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: appreciate the help! the result below doesn't seem to be what I was trying to get here are the resutls:

Comment: MATERIAL           Full Size ATP
------------------ -------------
AA2721             0
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: apologies the comments don't seem to like the output but I get the value of 0 and the warning thanks again!

Comment: I added COUNT(A.MATERIAL) and COUNT(*) to the query to see what they return. I used A.MATERIAL in the query because I assumed that if you're joining on that column then it shouldn't be NULL when A.AVAIL_QTY  is NOT NULL, and based on your question A.AVAIL_QTY is NOT NULL. Hard to say without seeing your data.

Comment: appreciate the help - I have updated the question above. In this I am using COUNT on the AVAIL_QTY to get the value 1 or 0.  In the second part I use @@ROWCOUNT to get the total # of rows for this material.  What I would like to do is SUM the COUNT which would be 2 and divide by the ROWCOUNT of 3....sorry for any confusion and thank you again.

Comment: in that last column my goal is to get 66% - 2/3  Thanks again.

Comment: I edited the query in the answer to match your edited question. My query gives you the result in a single step, you don't need to do it in separate steps. I made the assumption that if the available quantity is 0 (rather than NULL) then you wouldn't want to count it either - the NULLIF will take care of not counting rows where available quantity is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually figured it out with the help of a kind soul at the bar who happens to work for Microsoft (go figure)...The only issue remaining is the query he helped me build works for the 1 article I was testing, when I remove the MAX and change the material selection to IN...(several articles)...it stops working.  Any ideas on what may fix this?  Appreciate everyone's help - much gratitude. Edited the query above...it returns .66666667 or 2/3 just as I was looking for